# function prototype variable scope C++

Tags: c++

Are variables in function prototype declaration in C++ considered global in scope?

E.g. In the script below, we declare a function prototype of `readArray` that takes an array `integerArray` and integer `maxNumElements` as input and returns the number of elements the user has provided. Of course, the `readArray` function is called from main. My question is if `displayArray` can print the array edited in `readArray` by being provided the maximum number of elements the user has inserted. In short, are `integerArray` and `numElements` global?

```
/* prototype declaration*/
int readArray (int integerArray [], int maxNumElements);
void displayArray(int integerArray[], int numElements);

int main()
{
    int inputValues[128]; /*the array to be read*/
    int numberOfValues = readArray(inputValues, 128);
    displayArray(inputValues, numberOfValues);
    return 0;
}

int readArray(int integerArray[], int maxNumElements)
{
    int numberOfValues;
    for (numberOfValues = 0; numberOfValues < maxNumElements; numberOfValues++)
    { /*take integers as input from user and insert into array */
       /*return the number of elements the user as provided*/
    }
    return numberOfValues;
}

void displayArray(int integerArray[], int numElements)
{ /*print the array*/
    for (int = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ":" << integerArray[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Each function will have its own private and local *copy* of the variables.

Comment: Don't mess around with raw arrays. We already have `sdt::array`and `std::vector` implementtions in the c++ stanards.

Comment: Possibly not a real question. You can do it and see what happens. That is what we should do for any easy to test behaviors.

Comment: Go have a slow long read at:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm and answer what seems to be your question.

Answer (score 1):

Scope is about where names are visible. Names in global scope, for example, are visible from their point of declaration to the end of the translation unit in which they are declared; names in local scope are visible from their point of declaration to the end of the block in which they are declared (i.e., up to the closing `}`). The names of arguments in a function **prototype** are visible only in the prototype. The names of arguments that are passed to a function are visible throughout that function.

So, from your code:

```
int readArray(int integerArray[], int maxNumElements);
```

The names `integerArray` and `maxNumElements` are not visible outside this prototype.

```
int readArray(int integerArray[], int maxNumElements) {
    // ...
}
```

The names `integerArray` and `maxNumElements` are visible thoughout the function definition, but not outside it.

```
int displayArray(int intgerArray[], int numElements) {
    // ...
}
```

The names `integerArray` and `numElements` are visible thoughout the function definition, but not outside it.

The three uses of the name `integerArray` have no connection to each other; it's as if each of them was a completely different name.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it makes sense to speak of function parameters as variables. They basically serve as placeholder for data you will provide to the function when you call it.

So, in your example you are not operating on `integerArray`, rather you are operating on the data pointed to by `int inputValues[128]`, which you declare in `main()`. `inputValue` is the variable, not `integerArray`.

In your case you happen to be doing what is called call-by-reference. I.e. your function prototypes are receiving a pointer to an integer. When you pass the pointer `inputValues` to readArray:

```
int numberOfValues = readArray(inputValues, 128);
```

then you are giving it the address `inputValues`. `readValues` will then operate on the memory area pointed to by `inputValues`.

Thus, `displayArray` will display the data edited by `readArray` in your example.

Please note that this is a result of you doing a call-by-reference, not that the function parameters are in some sense in global scope.

If you function prototypes had looked something like this:

```
int readArray (vector<int> integerArray);
void displayArray(vector<int> integerArray);
```

Then `displayArray` would not be printing the content of `integerArray` in any sense. When you call `readArray`, you would be doing a call by-value: It would get a copy of `inputValues` (in that case it would be declared as `vector<int> inputValues`) and when the function call returns, you are left with the original value of `inputValues` and in this particular case, `displayArray` would print an empty vector.

Comment: Function parameters are really just a special kind of local variable, and are initialised when the function is called.  They can be in a register or in actual memory, just like other local variables.  Also, if you think about it, _all_ variables are just placeholders for data; they're really just names we use so we don't have to work directly with the registers and memory addresses themselves.

Comment: I guess you are right. I was just trying to get across to the OP that it is not always a useful concept to think about function parameters in the same way as "normal" variables, especially not when you are looking at the function declaration. In particular, in his example he may get the impression that the function parameter somehow has global scope, but in fact it may just look like it in his particular example, due to the call-by-reference. I think this is what is confusing him. I hope I have not added to that confusion, the intention was the opposite.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Just wanted to clarify that they're still variables, to clear up any potential misunderstandings.

Answer (score -2):

No, they are not global. Functions create a local copy while receiving a parameter. You can verify this in C++ by creating your own class with a cout inside the copy constructor. Pass object of that class to a function(by value) and you will see the copy constructor being invoked. In C++, better way is to use std::array and std::vector. Also passing by value is not a wise idea for non-primitive types and huge data chunks. Always pass parameters by "address" (pointers) or by "reference" (you may want to read about std::ref)

Comment: *"Always pass parameters by "address" or by "reference""* How is `const int &param` better than `int param`?

Comment: Note that for simple types (such as the built-in types, types with trivial constructors, or types that can fit inside a single register), it's often more efficient to pass by value unless you explicitly need to be able to modify the original.  Also note that passing by value can be more efficient when you're going to make a copy anyways, due to move semantics (you can move the local copy).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "const int &param" -> This has two things. First, receiving a parameter as const is a very good practice if you are not going to change the value of param in your function and want to avoid changing its value accidentally. Second, the "&param". Receiving a parameter as reference rather than value is also a very good practice, but is more meaningful when the parameter is of "big" type such as a class/structure object. It avoids a local copy of the huge chunk. In case of primitive types like int, this won't make a big difference. but still "const int &param" won't cause any harm.

Comment: I agree, const parameters have their own benefits; should've said `const int &` vs `const int`. And you're right, references on small types probably wont make much difference. I'm only arguing about *"passing by value is not a wise idea"* part, since passing by value is at least as fast for small types (and can be optimized to passing by reference for large ones).

Comment: @SumitJindal If we're being technical, taking an `int` by (`const`) reference will result in _very_ slightly less efficient code, although it typically won't be enough to matter outside of insanely performance-critical code.  (Except possibly on systems where `int` is larger than the word size, I'm not sure about how efficient passing `int` is there.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree. I should make that line more clear, someting like "passing by value is not a wise idea for non-primitive types or huge data". I will edit the comment :)

Comment: Specifically, if the compiler can't optimise things away, [passing an `int` by reference will generally result in 1-2 more instructions than passing it by value](https://godbolt.org/g/8wgQV9).

Comment: @JustinTime I completely agree with you. Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the answer. I agree that for small primitive types like int and char this concept won't make much sense.